Omitting and adding some
Consider these sentences:

She bought meat, butter, and potatoes yesterday.
She bought some meat, some butter, and some potatoes yesterday.

For me, the second one is a correct sentence, as she definitely bought some amount of meat, some amount of butter, and some number of potatoes. I'm not talking about meat, butter, and potatoes in general, as in the sentence:

"I love meat, butter, and potatoes."

Here, it's easy to see that I don't mean any specific amount/number of these things. I'm talking about classes (things in general).
I know that we shouldn't use some to contrast one class of things with another, as some will change the meaning of a sentence:

There is water in the bottle. (The bottle contains water. It doesn't contain tea, juice, coffee, etc.)
There is some water in the bottle. (There is some amount of water left in the bottle.)

Conclusion: our initial sentence doesn't contrast one class of things with another. It doesn't refer to substances and things in general. It refers to some amount of meat, some amount of butter and some number of potatoes. Therefore, I need to use some before the nouns.
I've studied some articles related to this problem. They mention that sometimes we can add and omit some with very little change in meaning. I guess that this is the case, but I cannot incorporate this guideline into my thought process as I don't understand the meaning of sometimes here.
I know that my conclusion is wrong, as the first version of the first sentence definitely exists. What do I miss? What do I need to add to my reasoning to be able to prove the correctness of the first version of the first sentence to myself?

UNLESS the word water is heavily stressed in (1) There is water in the bottle OR the word some is heavily stressed in (2) There is some water in the bottle, I can't think of any contexts where those two utterances have even a nuance of difference. You're seriously overthinking this one.

@FumbleFingers There is a statement in my grammar book: 'Words expressing indefinite quantity cannot be omitted in English'. This phrase led me here.

Words expressing indefinite quantity cannot be omitted in English sounds like nonsense to me. I had to think for a bit to come up with even one context where that's true: "Please wait. I'll just be a few minutes". In most contexts, elements like many, much, few, little, a number of, a great deal, some, several can be discarded - often with little or no effect on meaning.

Sentence 1 simply states that she bought three kinds of groceries; there is no need to explain that it was an unspecified quantity of each.

There’s no grand, overarching system of logic that can explain any natural language. The answer that both (a) is correct and (b) perhaps comes as close as possible to the patch that you seek for your reasoning is “That’s simply the way English works.”
The meaning of a sentence like I bought eggs can be paraphrased in substantial logical rigor by something like “There exist—or any way, existed—a number n > 1 of eggs, and I bought all n of those eggs.”

My idea was that 'I bought eggs' means that 'the type of the things that I bought is the egg type.' The sentence 'I bought some eggs' means 'I bought a certain number of things that belong to the egg type.' I thought that in the first version the type is in focus, but in the second one we aren't talking about the type; rather, we're talking about some unspecified number of instances of the type. Doesn't it sound completely wrong?

For native speakers there’s not really any such distinction meant or understood between I bought eggs and I bought some eggs. One could come up with special situations where one or the other version might be more natural, but in general they mean the same thing. As an example of the atypical, if asked, “But how many eggs did you buy?” one might answer, “I don’t know. Some! I bought some eggs. Now leave me alone.”

That's why I didn't put my idea about the difference in the meanings into the question itself. It appeared as the result of my attempt to generalize the examples with 'water' (that I've demonstrated in the question) and some similar ones. Thanks, Paul.

Fluent native speakers miss out words that are not needed. A child or ESL learner might write, 'I bought some eggs, and I bought some tomatoes, I bought some apples, and I bought some bananas'. An adult or native speaker might write 'I bought eggs, tomatoes, apples, and bananas'. It's called ellipsis.
